# Are there any API servers available for alt-coins that allow for transactions to be broadcast into their networks?

Tags: development, api, services, server

With blockchain.info we have the [pushtx](http://blockchain.info/pushtx) API that allow one to broadcast raw transactions into the network. It appears to be one of few services that offer such functionality. Are there any servers that offer such APIs for altcoins, or does one need to create their own / run their own version of altcoin'd to have access to such functionality?

Comment: I recently had to use an API for pushing Dogecoin transactions to the network, the dogechain.info API worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a program in python that does exactly this for Litecoin, Bitcoin, and Dogecoin. The program can connect to peers on any of the above mentioned crypto network and submit the transaction directly instead of relying on a third party central server to push the transaction out to the network.

It is available open source under https://github.com/kaykurokawa/pushtx